# Вычислить ширину контейнера на bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Для вывода меню нужно вычислить его ширину.
Если говорить в абсолютных значениях то он должна быть равна:
ширина контейнера "минус" ширина колонки "минус" ширина межколоночника (стандартно 30px)
Вот цифрами для широкого экрана
width: calc(1140px - 100% - 30px);
Помогите эту формулу сделать универсальной, которая считалась бы автоматически при изменении ширины экрана.

Comment: Добавьте пример вашего кода, добавьте скрин или подробно опишите как это должно выглядеть и работаь. Сейчас не могу понять, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: @E_K В идеале нужно получить такое меню как здесь: https://vezudivan.ru/ выпадающее в левой колонке